# Filtered array of local Model records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an array controller `ActivitiesController` which is responsible for managing a days worth of activities (versus the full set). I've set the `model` property of the `ActivitiesRoute` to the following:

```
return this.store.find('activity', {on_date: params.on_date});
```

This does pull back the appropriate records and I can see them all within the Ember debugger but for some reason these records aren't available to the template (`activities.hbs`). That was baffling to me but in reality that isn't the final solution anyway (i had just expected it to work).

What I really want to do is have the controller's content manage an array of **local** `Activity` records that have been filtered to the specified date. This filtered array then will periodically update based on asynchronous calls to an update query: `find('activity', {on_date: this.get('on_date'), since: this.get('since');`.

I hope that description makes sense. I've looked at other queries on SO and there were some promising starts but the answers all seemed to be dated and I could find anything that helped me crack this nut.

In summary, I want to:

1. Have the controller's `content` be an active filter on the local `Activity` records that correspond to a given date.
2. Be able to asynchronously push additional records onto the model which will automagically show on the controller (assuming they're for the appropriate date).

As an aside, I'd be particularly interested to know why my current `model` hook isn't available the activities template.

------------- UPDATE -------------

I have tried this in my model hook:

```
return this.store.filter('activity',function(activity){
    var itemDate = new Date(activity.get('start_time'));
    itemDate = moment(itemDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    return itemDate === params.on_date;
});
```

This should be inline with @Bradley's suggestion. I needed to truncate the time component so I added that logic using the moment.js library. This doesn't throw any errors but also doesn't pull any records from the server by itself so I added the following line of code into the model hook:

```
this.set('activities', this.store.find('activity', {on_date: params.on_date}));
```

Using the debugger I can see that the `ActivityRoute` has an `activities` property that is set as a `DS.PromiseArray` and I can see that the `activities` property has a length of 15 which is the number of activities for that day.

[image]

It also looks like the `currentModel` of `ActivityRoute` is set to a `DS.FilteredRecordArray` and it too has the appropriate 15 records in it but my handlebars template still has no ability to iterate over it. I assume this is because the `content` property of the `ActivityController` is not set. Why is this step not done by Ember in this situation? Do I need to force this or are there gremlins in the system that need teasing out?

Answer (score 2):

For local filtering you are looking for the [DS.Store#filter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter) function.

```
return this.store.filter('activity', function(activity) { 
  activity.get('on_date') === params.on_date
});
```

This returns a DS.FilteredRecordArray that live-updates with new/updated records

Comment: Shoot, I had looked for something like this and somehow missed it. Thanks. In the documentation there is reference to potential performance concerns over a large (or quickly updating) client recordset. Do you know of any examples of design pattern for adding a layer of abstraction to attend to this?

Comment: Oh and my "dummy" question for the day ... how do I just get a reference to all the "local" records of a given type without triggering a call to the server like `find()` does?

Comment: @ken, in that case `this.store.all('activity')` is your friend

Comment: I am excited about your comments but I'm still struggling to get this thing to work. It seems whatever I return from the `model` hook goes no where. I'll update the question with those unsuccessful results.

Comment: I've left a long-winded description of my current concern but I have worked around it by adding `controller.set('model',this.get('currentModel'));` into the `setupController` hook on the `ActivityRoute`.